# Oracle: ORA-14400 error while importing data from excel into table

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

I am trying to import data into table from a csv file, the column names are same and datatype matches. While i try to import I am hitting with below error.

[image]

DDL :

```
    CREATE TABLE "HR"."USER_PARTITION" 
       (    "SERIAL_ID" NUMBER, 
        "ACCOUNT_GUID" VARCHAR2(18 CHAR), 
        "MEMBER_ACCESS_LEVEL" VARCHAR2(80 CHAR), 
        "USER_GUID" VARCHAR2(18 CHAR), 
        "ACCOUNT_ACCESS_LEVEL" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR), 
        "SHARE_ACCOUNT_GUID" VARCHAR2(18 CHAR), 
        "CASE_ACCESS_LEVEL" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR), 
        "OPPORTUNITY_ACCESS_LEVEL" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR), 
        "USER_GROUP_GUID" VARCHAR2(18 CHAR), 
        "STATUS" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
        "TEAM_MEMBER_ROLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(180 CHAR), 
        "COUNTRY_CODE" VARCHAR2(60 CHAR), 
        "REGION" NUMBER, 
        "ACCOUNT_ID" NUMBER, 
        "BADGE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(18 CHAR), 
        "CREATION_DATE" DATE DEFAULT NULL, 
        "PROCESS_FLAG" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N', 
        "REC_INSERT_DATE" DATE
       ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
      STORAGE(
      BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
      PARTITION BY RANGE ("REGION") 
      SUBPARTITION BY LIST ("PROCESS_FLAG") 
(PARTITION "P_REGION1"  VALUES LESS THAN (2) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION1_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION1_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION2"  VALUES LESS THAN (3) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION2_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION2_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION3"  VALUES LESS THAN (4) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION3_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION3_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION4"  VALUES LESS THAN (5) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION4_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION4_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION5"  VALUES LESS THAN (6) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION5_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION5_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION6"  VALUES LESS THAN (7) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION6_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION6_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION7"  VALUES LESS THAN (8) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION7_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION7_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION8"  VALUES LESS THAN (9) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION8_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION8_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION9"  VALUES LESS THAN (10) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION9_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION9_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION10"  VALUES LESS THAN (11) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION10_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION10_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION11"  VALUES LESS THAN (12) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS  NOLOGGING 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION11_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION11_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION12"  VALUES LESS THAN (13) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS  NOLOGGING 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION12_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION12_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION13"  VALUES LESS THAN (14) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS  NOLOGGING 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION13_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION13_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION14"  VALUES LESS THAN (15) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS  NOLOGGING 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION14_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION14_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION15"  VALUES LESS THAN (16) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS  NOLOGGING 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION15_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION15_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION16"  VALUES LESS THAN (17) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS  NOLOGGING 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION16_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION16_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION17"  VALUES LESS THAN (18) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS  NOLOGGING 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION17_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION17_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION18"  VALUES LESS THAN (19) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS  NOLOGGING 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION18_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION18_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION19"  VALUES LESS THAN (20) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS  NOLOGGING 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION19_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION19_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) , 
 PARTITION "P_REGION20"  VALUES LESS THAN (21) 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS  NOLOGGING 
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_REGION20_Y"  VALUES ('Y') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS , 
  SUBPARTITION "P_REGION20_N"  VALUES ('N') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SC_DATA01" 
 NOCOMPRESS ) )  ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT
```

CSV file contains region column with regions 1-10

Here is the partition range values
**[image: PARTITION RANGE]**

INSERT STATEMENT:

```
INSERT INTO USER_PARTITION
  (SERIAL_ID, ACCOUNT_GUID, MEMBER_ACCESS_LEVEL, USER_GUID, 
   ACCOUNT_ACCESS_LEVEL, SHARE_ACCOUNT_GUID, CASE_ACCESS_LEVEL, 
   OPPORTUNITY_ACCESS_LEVEL, USER_GROUP_GUID, STATUS, 
   TEAM_MEMBER_ROLE_NAME, COUNTRY_CODE, REGION, ACCOUNT_ID, 
   BADGE_NUMBER, CREATION_DATE, PROCESS_FLAG,
   REC_INSERT_DATE)
VALUES
  (5095611237,'0017000000UWQ2WAAX','Edit','005A0000006zU2qIAE',
   'Edit','0017000000UWP2QAAX','Edit',
   'Edit','005A0000007cU2qIAE','I',
   '3rd Party Software TSR','FJ',1,2224808630,
   '1111441', to_date('29-Apr-22', 'DD-MON-RR'), '',
    to_date('29-Apr-22', 'DD-MON-RR'));
```

ERROR:
Error starting at line : 8 in command -

Error report -
ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition

Comment: Is this the solution:  https://dbaclass.com/article/ora-14400-inserted-partition-key-does-not-map-to-any-partition/

Answer (score 1):

Not all the new elements you have are matching one of your partitions. To solve this issue by the creation of one or more further partitions, like

```
alter table "HR"."USER_PARTITION" add partition <some name> values less than <the highest REGION in your csv + 1>;
```

Comment: I have added the image of the partitions and the range,  the file is exported from same table structure from other environment. dont know why it causing issue.

Comment: @kumar the very likely cause is that your other environment contains records that do not fall into any of your partitions. So, if you have a few partitions and the `high_value` is outside the bounds defined by any partitions that you have the error. Also, if a partition key is actually specified, but it doesn't exist, then you need to create the partition.

Comment: okay, even i tried to insert with insert statement for a single record it show same error. may be i need to check with dba team on this.

Comment: @kumar please edit your question with the following details: 1. What is the exact insert statement that fails, 2. The error message, 3. The partitions that you have. Those will clarify the situation. Once you edited your question with these details, please do let me know.

Comment: Added the details of complete DDL (includes partitions 1-20), insert statement (single record) and error message

Comment: @kumar the value for region was 2224808630. Can you edit your question with the partitions you have?

Answer (score 0):

Your table is partitioned by REGION, subpartitioned by PROCESS_FLAG. There are partitions for REGION = 1 through 20, and subpartitions in each region for PROCESS_FLAG in ('Y', 'N'). If you have any values in your spreadsheet for REGION which are not in the range of 1..20, or values for PROCESS_FLAG which are not 'Y' or 'N' then you'll get the error you're getting. You'll have to check your data and identify the row(s) which have values which are not in the list of valid values above, and then either fix the data or add partitions to your table.

Comment: Okay. i have data only in regions 1-10 and process_flag='N' according to my requirement. is it that you are saying i should have data belonging to 11-20 regions and process_flag=Y as well or no need.

Comment: In the INSERT statement shown the value for PROCESS_FLAG is `''`, which the database will interpret as NULL. The database does not know where to store a row where PROCESS_FLAG is NULL so it throws this error. Fix the PROCESS_FLAG.

Comment: I tried to insert the PROCESS_FLAG as 'N' it gives same error